# How to add two columns in a data frame to create a new third column, based on sub-strings of column names, in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Lets consider a simple data frame as follows :

```
id area1feature1 area1feature2 area2feature1 area2feature2
1  1             2             3             4
2  3             6             1             5
```

Now I would like to combine `feature1` for all areas, `feature2` for all areas and so on, and then create a new `sumOfFeature1`, `sumOfFeature2`, etc.

So the expected output is something like this :

```
id area1feature1 area1feature2 area2feature1 area2feature2 sumOfFeature1 sumOfFeature2
1  1             2             3             4             4             6
2  3             6             1             5             4             11
```

How can I match columns based on sub-string and then combine them to create new columns for data frame?

Comment: the first data frame is in a hard format to work with since your column names also contain id variables.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: @miles2know - I don't know why that is problematic at all.

Comment: @thelatemail One way I can think of is to apply `grep()` like function to `colnames()` of a dataframe.

Comment: @Sangram - that would be the way I'd go, e.g. `sapply(c("feature1","feature2"), function(x) rowSums(dat[grepl(x,colnames(dat))] ))`

Comment: @thetamail it's not a problem but I don't think its the best way to encode grouping variables.

Comment: @thelatemail nice suggestion though. I'd melt it first. Then do some joins.

Comment: @miles2know - definitely, it's not an ideal structure. But sometimes you work with what you've got :-)

Comment: @thetamail agreed. after melts grep and such would be worthy ways forward. best.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it is as follows :
Let `input` be the data frame.

```
features_to_be_combined <- c('feature1', 'feature2')
locations <- sapply(features_to_be_combined, grep, colnames(input))
feature1_locations <- locations[, 'feature1']
sumOfFeature1 <- rep(0, dim(input)[1])
for (i in 1:length(feature1_locations)) {
    sumOfFeature1 <- sumOfFeature1 + input[, feature1_locations[i]]
}
```

Now all that remains is to repeat the same procedure for `feature2` and then add newly created features, namely `sumOfFeature1` and `sumOfFeature2`, to the `input` data frame.
I am sure there will a better way to do this (may be using `apply` again on combined features), but this worked for me as expected.